# Making a smooth Sinusoidal wave with CSS animation and SVG worknig for someone elses SVG but not mine?

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

Animation of the problem (theirs vs mine). More context below:

[image]

I have gotten some code off of JSFiddle and it is as follows:
HTML:

```
<article id="main">
    <div class="ocean">
        <div class="wave"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.ocean { 
    height: 5%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background: #015871;
  }

  .wave {
    background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85486/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 6400px;
    top:-198px;
    height:198px;
    animation: wave 2s linear infinite;
  }


  @keyframes wave {
    100% {
      margin-left: -1600px;
    }
  }

  article{
      width:100%;
      height:100vh;
  }
```

Now with me, I have the exact same code, but I changed out the source to an svg that I made by changing the 'background' attribute in the '.wave' class as follows:

```
background: url("...\my_svg.svg");
```

Then this is the code for that SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 65">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>bkg-side</title>
    <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1600.3,58.38c-64.8,0-177.4-9.65-400-28.94S866.52.5,800.4.5C735.6.5,623,10.15,400.45,29.44S66.62,58.38.5,58.38v6.89l1600,.23"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Now as you'll see, there is a smooth transition for the svg that I am using and a not-so-smooth transition with the SVG that I made. Theirs will scroll infinitely to the side or at least look like it is while mine will 'reset' after the set amount of time for the animation (in this case, 5 seconds). The only difference in code is which SVG is being used and I have no idea why their SVG will scroll to the side infinitely and look like a smooth curve, while with mine, it resets and gets choppy every 5 seconds. Does it have something to do with the SVG code in of itself?

EDIT: the ends DO touch each other forming a consistent curve with both images, and I have put my image in the top left corner of Illustrator and hit 'Export Selection...'. The consistancy is there, but with this one, the wave goes on without resetting while mine DOES reset from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your wave is in the middle of a large SVG, with space all around it.  Whereas theirs occupies the full width of the SVG.

When you `repeat-x` theirs, the left and right edges of each repeat meet up.  Yours have large gaps on the left and right.

You need to move your wave shape to the left edge of the SVG and trim the page size to match the width.

Comment: I don't think that's it as I've put it in the top corner just now and still did the same thing. The wave itself is continuous with both images. The ends touch each other just fine in both images. The problem is that it will start again from the beginning after the time loops. I'll try to add a .gif to make this clearer

Added this point in an edit to the question.

Comment: Make sure the `width` of your SVG and the `margin-left` in the `@keyframes` rule match.  For instance, in the original they are both 1600.

Comment: FIXED: It was the attributes for the svg that were the problem. Details below in the answer that I provided. Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

Based on Paul's comment, and by comparing the svg files, I found that THEIR svg didn't have a viewbox attribute and had a width attribute, while mine DID have a viewbox attribute and didn't have a width attribute. I set the with to be the value of the margin-left value in the @key-frames animation and presto!

My old svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 65">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>bkg-side</title>
    <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1600.3,58.38c-64.8,0-177.4-9.65-400-28.94S866.52.5,800.4.5C735.6.5,623,10.15,400.45,29.44S66.62,58.38.5,58.38v6.89l1600,.23"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

My new svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1600" height="66">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>bkg-side</title>
    <g id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1">
        <path class="cls-1" d="M1600.3,58.38c-64.8,0-177.4-9.65-400-28.94S866.52.5,800.4.5C735.6.5,623,10.15,400.45,29.44S66.62,58.38.5,58.38v6.89l1600,.23"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```